# Can't connect to smb-share from specific other networks

Tags: linux, windows, networking, port, smb

I created a smb-share (HDDs Raid1 plus a Cache-SSD) on my Linux-server, and opened a port to connect to it from everywhere via a DDNS service. Everything is working fine, I can connect to my share from outside of my network, and the speeds are great for my application (automatic Backup/Syncing of Data).

The problem that now arose is that my Windows Laptop keeps throwing random error messages at me when trying to connect to my share from the network of my university. Is it possible to block such specific traffic in a network, and how can I circumvent that?

I tried every Windows setting from Public and private networks, filesharing enabled, etc. I would be very happy if someone could please explain this behavior to me, I'd like to understand what's happening

Comment: "Is it possible to block such specific traffic in a network, and how can i circumvent that?" - Can you be more specific about what error messages you have received and what traffic you are interested in blocking.  You should [edit] your question instead of replying with a comment

Comment: SMB should not be exposed to the whole internet. Instead you may want to set up a VPN, like wireguard, on your server. This could also help you to overcome the restrictions in your universities network.